# Is it possible to compile a project with a prototype of the function but not its body?

Tags: c, compilation

I am writing a project that I have to write only a part of it, the problem is that under an if condition I want to call a function that someone else writes. I have the prototype of that function but I don't have its body.

so the linker gives me an error. Is it possible to compile the code without commenting the function call?

Here is the code i am trying to compile, any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void);

int main(void)
{
    char c = getchar();
    if (c=='a'){ foo(); }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without the proper function, you can compile it but your code will not be able to run - for obvious reasons. Is that not a problem?

Comment: .. if it is: ask the other person to do a compile-but-not-link for just that function and send the object file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to compile the code without commenting the function
>   call?

Yes. You just need to compile it without linking it. For example, using gcc's `-c` option:

```
gcc -c foo.c -o foo
```

Comment: My understanding is he also wants to run his program.

Comment: @ouah: no he does not. I double-checked that before upvoting the obvious answer :)

Comment: Visual studio provides a similar [option too](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8we9bhf4.aspx).

Comment: @l3x any compiler does

Comment: It's not just gcc's option, `-c` is a standard option for all C compilers on UNIX-like platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a mock implementation of your module that just does nothing:

E.g., `foo.c` file:

```
void foo(void)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Until that someone else writes the body of the function you can simply add your own dummy definition:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void);

void foo(void) {
    // TODO remove this, pending real foo definition
}

int main(void)
{
    char c = getchar();
    if (c=='a'){ foo(); }   
    return 0;
}
```